# How to create customized cvs files from excel?

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8

I am a linguist, not a programmer or Excel guru.

I have an excel file like this:

- `A column:` Master Language (en_US, en_GB etc)
- `B Column:` English master sentence
- `C Column:` Translation of X language. and first row has language code like (de_DE)
- `D, E, F... columns:` translation of each and different languages.

The number of lines are unlimited. What I need to create tab delimited UTF-8 csv files like that:

```
en_US \t English master sentence in row 2 \t de_DE \t translation in row 2

en_US \t English master sentence in row 3 \t de_DE \t translation in row 3
```

- `en_US` will be retrieved from Column A.
- `\t` would be a tab.
- `English master sentence` will be retrieved from Column B.
- `de_DE` will be in first row of each relevant column.
- Translation will be retrived from relevant column.

I am stuck with that. I will have either option of doing it manually for each language or having a macro to do it after preparing the Excel.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Comment: I am sorry if I give such an impression. Of course I don't see SO as code writing service. I am already reading comments, solutions and so on. I tried macro recording. But it doesn't help:( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a text file for output and then cycle through the worksheet and output each row to the CSV, then you'll need to open the file for output, then cycle through the sheet with a for next loop, building the CSV rows with Print statements.  See "How to write in txt file with vba" (put "22907176" in the search bar at the top of this page) to get started.  Tab is Chr(9), so you'll use a statement such as

```
print #1, cells(counter,1) & chr(9) & cells(counter,2)
```

Is that what you're after?